# ActiveRecord date field with non-english text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have a form submitting to a controller action with a field that is in the `"%B %d, %Y"` date format.  Our site has recently added multi-language support and now this is breaking when we translate the text in the field to non-english.

Example in ENGLISH: (This works as expected and populates the field with a date)

`@model.datetime_field = "May 01, 2016"`

Example in GERMAN. (This will not assign the field with a date)

`@model.datetime_field = "Mai 01, 2016"`

I've looked into the ActiveRecord source code and also at a few gems (like Alchemy) and I haven't found this problem to be solved.  Please don't suggest that I change the form value, because due to the nature of the application/business requirements it needs to stay as is. Also to note, I need the solution to work for mass-assignment, e.g. `@model.save(params[:model])` and `@model.update(params[:model])`

Does anyone know if there is something in Rails/rails-18n/3rd-party gem that solves this problem or do I have to write my own custom parser?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This gem looks like it does what you want:

https://github.com/clemens/delocalize